# Problem with assigning the keyboard shortcut with left Ctrl and left Shift

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, shortcut

I have a problem with assigning the shortcuts with L CTR and L Shift.

some shortcuts it's working fine like
`L Ctrl + L Shift + I` , `L Ctrl + L Shift + Q` and etc.
But when I'm trying to assign `L Ctrl + L Shift + K` or `L Ctrl + L Shift + Enter` etc.. it's not working for me!

But when I'm trying to assign the `R Ctrl + R shift + Enter` it's working fine!

Notes:
All keyboard buttons work fine.
The problem is with all software that I want to assign shortcuts to it with `L Ctrl + L Shift + ?`

I checked my keyboard with [This online services to check the keyboard button](http://en.key-test.ru/), so when I press on `R Ctrl + R shift + Enter` at the same time isn't working!